# JasperReports Server - Allowing user input multiple dates

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Is there a way to allow the user to input multiple dates and have the report filtered on those selected dates? For example:

```
Loan Table: 

Loan#   Date
1   11/1/2013
2   11/2/2013
3   11/3/2013
4   11/4/2013
5   11/5/2013
```

User select: 11/01/2013 & 11/03/2013

```
Results:    
Loan#   Date
1   11/1/2013
3   11/3/2013
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about *JR Server*?

Comment: JasperReport server ..yes.